# infinite loop in useEffect working with object

Tags: reactjs, loops, react-hooks, use-effect, infinite

hello how can I stop loop? everything works well but its looping during the clicking,when selectedfightersqry equal to one. initially it is 0 and incrementing on click

```
const handleClick = (id, player) => {
    getFighterInfo(id);
    setSelectedPlayer(player);
    setSelectedFightersQty(selectedFightersQty + 1);
    setFightersData(selectedFightersData)
    
  };
  
useEffect(()=>{
  if(selectedFightersQty===1){
    setFightersData({
      ...selectedFightersData,
      playerOne:fighter
    })
  }else if(selectedFightersQty===2){
    setFightersData({
      ...selectedFightersData,
      playerTwo:fighter
    })
  }
 
},[selectedFightersQty, selectedFightersData])
```

Comment: [selectedFightersQty.selectedFightersData] is undefined, because selectedFightersQty is not an object as @MORE mentioned. do you mean [selectedFightersQty] or [selectedFightersQty,selectedFighterData]?! If selectedFightersQty is state, you don't need to use [selectedFightersQty] at the end of useeffect. Because  changing the state causes  update the Page by itself and you can just add empty array to stop the loop :[ ]

Comment: sorry it was my mistake, yes I mean  [selectedFightersQty, selectedFighterData]

Comment: Can you try removing `selectedFightersData` from the dependency array once @Alexander ?

Comment: Fixed it.  i wrote fighter as a dependency instead of selectedFightersData. thanks guys <3 @ShubhankarKG